# Most pythonic way to use len() based conditions with multiple arguments in a list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, syntax, list-comprehension

1) What is the most pythonic way to use multiple conditional if statements in a list comprehension?

2) Len() returns an error if strings are concatenated when calling the function.

```
 Len(str(x) + str(y)) is not allowed
```

**Point 2 is incorrect but left for future readers**

Is lambda the appropriate function to use when using an if len() statement as follows:
?

```
for j in blah:
       for i in range(4):
           inputs = set([ str(j) + "".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(total, i) if 14 > len(lambda j,x : str(j) + "".join(x)) and len(lambda j, x : str(j) + "".join(x)) > 9])
```

Comment: I would curse you if I had to maintain `inputs = set([ str(j) + "".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(total, i) if 14 > len(lambda j,x : str(j) + "".join(x)) and len(lambda j, x : str(j) + "".join(x)) > 9])`. That is not Pythonic.

Comment: The Pythonic solution is likely not using a list (or better yet set) comprehension here at all but rather a regular for loop. This is pretty messy.

Comment: it is `len` not `Len`.  And you 2nd point is incorrect.  `len('a' + 'b') == 2`

Comment: You're taking the `len` of a lambda, which is a function. That doesn't make sense and will fail.

Comment: you can chain your comparators to get `9 < len(lambda j, x: str(j) + "".join(x)) < 14` its helps readablity, *a bit*

Comment: There's a bit of a thing on SO where it's attractive to create 1-liners but it should not be at the expense of readability. Keep in mind that what you wrote also violates PEP8 in terms of length so it will have to be broken over several lines. That actually might help with readability.

Comment: Consider making this a running example and include desired output. That would include fixing the `len(lambda)` problem. Its easy to write a simpler statement that will generate the same exception.

Comment: As for `len(lamba...)` - `lambda` creates a function object. You would need to call the function and take the length of its result. It makes no sense in this context. If you just want to run the code, do `(str(j) + "".join(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work and you don't have sample input and output for verification, so I'm taking a guess here. I see `str(j) + "".join(x)` multiple times and that's a good indicator that the generators are in the wrong order. You are doing `str(j)` a lot which hints some preprocessing is in order. It also helps to name variables in a way that makes it clear what they are. And adding spacing to keep lines short and in logical groupings makes it easier to scan later.

```
import itertools

blah = [10**n for n in range(5,15)]
total = 'fubar'

for blahval, permlen in itertools.product(map(str,blah), range(4)):
    inputs = set((newinput for newinput in
        (blahval + "".join(permutation)
            for permutation in itertools.permutations(total, permlen))
        if 14 > len(newinput) > 9))
```